# Method not working as Planned?

Tags: java, arrays, string, while-loop, return

```
Scanner adjectives = new Scanner(new File("adjectives.txt"));
        String[] adjectiveArray;
        adjectiveArray = new String[25];
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter<25)
        {
            String in = adjectives.next();
            fixCapitalization(in);
            adjectiveArray[counter]=in;
            counter++;
        }
```

Is my main code and my method that I'm trying to use is...

```
public static String fixCapitalization(String original)
{
    String modified = original.toLowerCase();
    return Character.toUpperCase(modified.charAt(0)) + modified.substring(1);

}
```

I'm attempting to fix the capitalization of the word before I put it into the array, but later on in my program I noticed that the words in adjectiveArray hadn't been capitalized? Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`String` is immutable

replace

```
fixCapitalization(in);
adjectiveArray[counter] = in;
```

with

```
adjectiveArray[counter] = fixCapitalization(in);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way .. Just do

`adjectiveArray[counter] = fixCapitalization(in);`

Answer (score 1):

You ignored the return of `fixCapitalization`.  Try changing

```
fixCapitalization(in);
```

to

```
in = fixCapitalization(in);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return value from `fixCapitalization()` method like this, because String is immutable and it will not change the value of the same String that you're passing to `fixCapitalization()`.

So try this:

```
String in = adjectives.next();
in = fixCapitalization(in);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the string returned from the Method - fixCapitalization
Here is the code, that fixes this issue.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


class test {
    public static void main() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner adjectives = new Scanner(new File("adjectives.txt"));
        String[] adjectiveArray= new String[25];
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter<25){
            String in = adjectives.next();
            adjectiveArray[counter]=fixCapitalization(in);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    public static String fixCapitalization(String original){
        String modified = original.toLowerCase();
        return Character.toUpperCase(modified.charAt(0)) + modified.substring(1);
    }
}
```